# Laravel - Eloquent multiple delete vs destroy array

Tags: laravel, optimization, laravel-5, eloquent, query-optimization

I was wondering what's the best way to destroy multiples database entries with ELOQUENT and I don't find a way to determine that.

So I have 3 array of id's (2 with ints, 1 with strings).
Is it better to go with a foreach and ->delete() every entry or destroy the array ?

When I look at the [destroy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#deleting-models) function, it states the following :

> We will actually pull the models from the database table and call 
>   delete on each of them individually so that their events get fired
>   properly  with a correct set of attributes in case the developers
>   wants to check  these.

And the code clearly shows :

```
$key = $instance->getKeyName();

foreach ($instance->whereIn($key, $ids)->get() as $model) {
    if ($model->delete()) {
        $count++;
    }
}
```

So I guess there's no real difference and the destroy function is just to avoid the use of a foreach. Can anyone confirm or inform and explain ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first you need to know the difference between destroy and delete, destroy is think to be used for removing an entity (object/model) and delete for being used on a query builder.

Both are different ways but they have the same purpose you can do like:

```
Model::destroy(array(1, 2, 3));
```

or

```
$ids = explode(",", [1,2,3]);
$model->find($ids)->each(function ($model, $key) {
    //Do things before deleting 
    $model->delete();
});
```

But as you can see the first one is just more direct, on the second one you can do custom *things* before deleting.

Comment: Thanks, I had that part figured out. I was more wondering in term of efficiency or SQL query time.

Comment: @MTH In terms of efficiency both are equals, the only difference is if you do too much things before deleting, but it will not change the performance of deteling itself.